# iOS UITableView scrollbar goes under table header when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a nib that is added as a UITableView header in a pretty standard way, like so:

```
self.headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameHeaderView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

but when the tableview scrolls the scrollbar goes under the header view, has anyone seen this before?

[image: scroll bar]

Comment: have you try sending headerview to back using method tableView.sendSubviewToBack:subview

Comment: i hadn't, tried it now but doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInset(self.headerview.height,0,0,0);
```

Comment: unfortunately that would only work if the tableviews bounce was disabled, which in my case is not

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions...

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.headerview.height, 0, 0, 0);
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO; 
}
```

//OR

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=YES;//it is YES by default
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: maybe my question was a bit ambiguous, but the scroll bar has the right insets currently, its just that it goes under (in terms of z ordering) the header view.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the same issue!